# SVA Repetition Non-Consecutive Operation Qualifying Event

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have the following property:

```
property p;
  @(posedge clk) a |=> b[=2] ##1 c;
endproperty
```

It tell us that if `a` is asserted, then start from the next `clk`, `b` should be asserted non-consecutively two times followed by `c` is asserted anytime after the last `b`.

My question is what if `c` is asserted in between the first `b` and the second `b`. Should the assertion fail immediately or continue on?
Some reference book says that it should fail, but I doubt it. What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[=` or **non-consecutive repetition operator** is similar to *goto repetition*, but the expression **need not be true** in the clock cycle before `c` is true.

Let's say `a` is asserted. The **implication condition** is **satisfied** and assertion is further evaluated.

Thereafter, `b` is checked **two times**, **no matter** what `c` is. Once `b` is **found to be asserted** for two non-consecutive clock edges, **thereafter** `c` is checked after 1-clock cycle (due to `##1`).

If `c` is **asserted** and **de-asserted** when `b` is **being checked** for 2 times, then that toggling is **not** considered. What of `c` is considered is **after** 2 assertions of `b`.

Following snaps shall give a clear idea:

Passing snap:

[image: Pass]

Fail snap:

[image: Fail]

Here, even though there was a glitch in `c`, the assertion didn't went through.

Refer to [A Practical Guide for SystemVerilog Assertions pdf](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb137011) for more details.
[Doulos tutorial](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/) is also a good one.

Comment: Does it also work for the `goto repetition` (I meant when `b` is being check two times, we can ignore `c`? ie whether this sequence will fail: `a !b b c !c !b b c` if we use either `goto repetition` or `non-consecutive repetition`?

Comment: Don't look for `c` when `b` is being checked. For the mentioned sequence, `c` is detected after checking for `b`, two times. So, neither of the two shall fail, both will **pass**. But, if you have something like `a !b b !b b !b c`, then *goto repetition* will fail, but *non-consecutive repetition* will pass. And yes, this applies to goto repetition also.

Comment: Ok now I understand and agree with you. I just got confused by the statement in the link given by you: https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/ where in similar property it says: `This means a is followed by any number of clocks **where c is false**, and b is true between 1 and three times, the last time being the clock before c is true.` Are they making wrong statement here (require c to be false when b is being checked)?

Comment: oh, its a matter of interpretation, there is **no strict** condition that **c should be false**. Just that `c` is not checked at that simulation time.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes it will pass. Regardless of where c is asserted, after two "b"s are observed, it will wait until c==1. So, if c was 1 from the beginning and never goes to zero, it will pass too.

One more point to make is when this assertion will actually fail. It will pass when c is asserted, but if not, it will keep running until the end of the test! You will see the failure only at the end of simulation.